# Rails ajax post response undefined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, routes

I'm trying to submit an ajax post request to a `create` action in a controller but I am getting `undefined` instead of a json response in the ajax `success` function. I need a json response because I'm building a single page app.

I'm using `render :json => {name: "jim"}.to_json`. Is this the correct way to go about it or is there something fundamental about ajax requests I'm missing?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Client-side ajax post request:

```
  submit_click: ->
    $.post "/responses",
      type: "POST"
      dataType: "json"
      contentType: "application/json"
      charset="utf-8"
      response:
        image_id: @image_name
        data: @data_pool
      success: (json) ->
        console.log json
```

Action in the Response controller:

```
  def create
    @response = Response.new(response_params)
    if @response.save
      count = count_completed_responses
      if count < 20
        render :json => {name: "jim"}.to_json
      end
    end
  end
```

EDIT: I can see the response coming through in the network tab of the chrome developer console - {name: "jim"}. Why can I not access it in the ajax success callback?

2nd EDIT: I actually got this to work by using the following after the `$post` function:

```
.done (data)
  console.log data
```

Anyone know why this works and the other way doesn't?

Comment: you no need to use `type: "POST"`. The method itself will make a POST request.

Comment: `charset="utf-8"` is also wrong syntax. I don't know how are you able to make call to the server :)

Comment: Have a look in data.detail.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like below

```
submit_click: ->
  $.post "/responses",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    dataType: 'json'
    response:
      image_id: @image_name
      data: @data_pool
    success: (json) ->
      console.log json
```

Hope it will work for you

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that didn't work - console log still outputs undefined